# Как убрать, скрыть стандартную панель управления windows?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

[image]

Как можно убрать эту стандартную голубую рамку вместе с ее панелью управления, я видел как приложение ее как то просто закрывали стилем, может кто знает?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/widgets-windowflags.html) пример и обратите внимание на флажок FramelessWindow. [Эта](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qws-simpledecoration.html) ссылка также может быть полезна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MainWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```